# How to write a Reactive extension to observe the change in a string property or parent class, provided by iOS

Tags: rx-swift

I am inheriting `SLComposeServiceViewController`. It has a `contentText` String that contains the text entered in one of its views. I want to write an extension like `extension Reactive where Base: SLComposeServiceViewController` to be able to observe any changes in the value of this variable.

I can't find proper syntax examples for achieving this

I tried something like

```
extension Reactive where Base: SLComposeServiceViewController {
  public func controlProperty<T>(
    editingEvents: ControlProperty<String> ,
    getter: @escaping (Base) -> T,
    setter: @escaping (Base, T) -> Void
  ) -> ControlProperty<T> {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SLComposeServiceViewController` doesn't provide a way to observe the `contentText` property so there is no hook that Rx can use to wrap it into an Observable. However, the class' `textView` property does have such a hook and the Observable is already provided inside RxCocoa.

Try this:

```
extension Reactive where Base: SLComposeServiceViewController {
    public var contentText: ControlProperty<String> {
        return base.textView.rx.string // could be rx.text if you are using UIKit instead of AppKit
    }
}
```